# How to get data from a string

Tags: php, arrays

I did a GET Request to an API REST and i got some data (base64 encoded).

Now i need to get some speceific values from the result but i don't know how.

**This is what i have so far**

```
<?php

    //BUSCAR DOCUMENTOS
    $service_url = 'http://192.168.4.77/api/Core.svc/core/PaginatedSearch/P/E/KFRpcG9EVEU6MzMgQU5EIEZjaEVtaXM6WzIwMTktMDYtMjEgVE8gMjAxOS0wNy0zMF0p/0/10';     
    $ch = curl_init($service_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'AuthKey: top-secret',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Accept: application/json',
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);

    if ($err) {

    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;

    } else {

        $datos = json_decode($response,true);

        foreach ($datos as $k => $v) {
            $Result = $datos['Result'];
            $Description = $datos['Description'];
            $SearchTime = $datos['SearchTime'];
            $TotalDocuments = $datos['TotalDocuments'];
            $Data = $datos['Data'];
        }
        $test = base64_decode($Data);
        var_dump($test);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**This is what i got, and need to get the values** (**Example**: 33 2284 21-06-2019 0:00:00)

```
string(3340) " <_DocID>37753825 <_Group>1 No 33 2284 21-06-2019 0:00:00 2 77606550-1 SOCIEDAD DE TURISMO RIO SERRANO S.A. Rio Serrano Hotel + 79800310-0 dte@comapa.cl TURISMO COMAPA LTDA dte@comapa.cl 314162 50160 264002 0 Outdoors 0 Punta Arenas Ultima Esperanza PUNTA ARENAS PUNTA ARENAS 521111 Correcta V?lida Si Si Espera Acuse Recibo Si 21-06-2019 9:24:31 Enviado 37753825 77606550-1\sent\33\2019\06\21\T033N000000000002284S776065501R798003100D20190621.xml Indefinido No No 21-06-2019 9:30:04 Indefinido 21-07-2019 16:55:01 <_DocID>37754716 <_Group>1 No 33 2285 21-06-2019 0:00:00 2 77606550-1 SOCIEDAD DE TURISMO RIO SERRANO S.A. Rio Serrano Hotel + 79800310-0 dte@comapa.cl TURISMO COMAPA LTDA dte@comapa.cl 314162 50160 264002 0 Outdoors 0 Punta Arenas Ultima Esperanza PUNTA ARENAS PUNTA ARENAS 521111 Correcta V?lida Si Si Espera Acuse Recibo Si 21-06-2019 9:47:31 Enviado 37754716 77606550-1\sent\33\2019\06\21\T033N000000000002285S776065501R798003100D20190621.xml Indefinido No No 21-06-2019 9:50:22 Indefinido 21-07-2019 16:55:13 "
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Who did this to you? Giving you data like that.

Comment: I recommend stripping the `AuthKey` from this example code. I assume this is intended to be a private, non-shared value.

Comment: @paskl is the API of an electronic billing company

Comment: @B.Fleming thanks, i deleted it !

Comment: Is it possible that the raw data--i.e. not the data that was pasted into the question--is tab-delimited? That is, is it possible that distinct sections of data are actually separated by `Tab`/`\t` characters? Also, is it possible that another portion of the data--say, `$Result` or `$Description`--contains better data or information that would help with retrieving a specific column from `$Data`?

Comment: There could be some separators, as @B.Fleming suggested, that could be completely missed depending on how you're viewing the data. I would definitely recommend exploring the data with perhaps [addcslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data is fairly structured, even if a complete mess.

There seems to be a key denotation `<_DocID>`, the key, a value denotation `<_Group>`, the value, and then it continues repeating. Using that, we can break it down at least into an associative array that is a bit more sensible.

```
$structured_response = [];
$keys = explode('<_DocID>', $response); //First we'll look for the keys

foreach ($keys as $key) {
  if ($key == '') continue;
  $data  = explode('<_Group>', $key); //Then we'll look for what's around on either side of the value denotation
  $key   = $data[0]; //Before the key-ending separator will be the key
  $value = $data[1]; //After the separator will be the data

  $structured_response[$key] = $value; //Now save the data to the array
}
```

Comment: This just overwrites the values, so you get 1 result in the end.

Comment: I failed to realize it was the same two key values each time, let me revise this.

Comment: Otherwise it seams like a very neat solution. I was working on something like getting a XML out of it somehow which you could parse. But I threw away that code once I saw your idea. Kudos. :)

Comment: @zbee thanks my friend, now to print the results i should do a var_dump, print_r, echo on the $structured_response[$key] var or not?

Comment: I appreciate it; I'm always looking for good uses of `explode()` haha. I like the idea of making it parse-able XML a lot actually, I wonder how that might look - I may try that.

Comment: By the way, this still only fetches the last occurence of $key. In the original data you have 2 `_DocID`, but you only save the last occurance (overwriting it actually). So maybe its just a `$structured_response[][$key]` ?

Comment: Getting XML out of it: shenanigens with str_replace to proper close the non closed tags. But then it gets shitty because you have just 1 big field with `_Group` and then I couldnt think of a solution on how to store "each" value into 1 field within the group. I dont know if they are tab seperated, or something which makes this kinda hard and not really reliable if the API decide to change stuff around. Thats why I asked who did this to him.

Comment: @paskl I am overwriting `$key` and `$value`, but I'm also appending them to the array.
@AlexSebastianOyarznFigueroa If you `var_dump($structured_response)` outside and after the loop then I believe you'll get a good overview of the now-structured data.

Comment: Yeah, in testing this I got `array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "37753825 " [1]=> string(480) "..." ["37754716 "]=> string(479) "..." }`

Comment: @zbee almost done, but i have an error and i dont know why, this is what i have: https://ibb.co/kxQvzCw sorry for the inconvenience i'm a noob yet xD

Comment: @AlexSebastianOyarznFigueroa My apologies, if you use my latest answer's code with the conditional in the loop then that should fix that issue.

Comment: @zbee still not working, i don't know if i'm doing something bad, i attach you another pic: https://ibb.co/cJpd94T i really need to resolve this sorry

Comment: @AlexSebastianOyarznFigueroa It seems like you might have an extra character that you didn't put in your question. Try implementing this conditional instead: `if (trim($key) == '') ... ` to account for extra spaces at the beginning of the response.

Comment: @zbee i'm 100% sure that i copy-pasted the "string(3340)" with the info decoded, and i'm still having the same error :(

Comment: @zbee there are spaces before the <_DocID> and before the last quotation marks, could be that the problem?

Comment: The space at the very beginning of the string should be the problem. I will have to look at this later, I am about to be busy; apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197292/discussion-between-zbee-and-alex-sebastian-oyarzn-figueroa).

Comment: Issues were resolved in that chatroom, with a `if (count($data) < 2) continue;` conditional in place of the conditional for `$key == ''`.